# Trying to make erase uiimage with swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, crop, erase, uigraphicscontext

I'm trying to make eraser feature(and restore in future) for my app but facing some problems. I'm using Swift 4.2 and this what I made so far:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first as UITouch?{
            let touchPoint = touch.location(in: self.lassoImageView) + lassoOffset!
            print("touch begin to : \(touchPoint)")
            eraserStartPoint = touchPoint   
        }
    }
```

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first as UITouch?{
            let touchPoint = touch.location(in: self.lassoImageView) + lassoOffset!
            print("touch moved to : \(touchPoint)")
            erase(fromPoint: eraserStartPoint!, toPoint: touchPoint)
            eraserStartPoint = touchPoint
        }
    }
```

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first as UITouch?{
            let touchPoint = touch.location(in: self.lassoImageView) + lassoOffset!
            print("touch ended at : \(touchPoint)")
            erase(fromPoint: touchPoint, toPoint: touchPoint)
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(lassoImageView.frame.size)
                lassoImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: lassoImageView.frame.size.width, height: lassoImageView.frame.size.height), blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)
                lassoImageView.image?.draw(in:  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: lassoImageView.frame.size.width, height: lassoImageView.frame.size.height), blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)
                lassoImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()   
    }
```

```
func erase(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(lassoImageView.bounds.size, false, 1)
        //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(lassoImageView.bounds.size)
        //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(lassoImageView.image!.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        lassoImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: lassoImageView.frame.size.width, height: lassoImageView.frame.size.height))
        //lassoImageView.image?.draw(in: calculateRectOfImageInImageView(imageView: lassoImageView))

        context?.move(to: fromPoint)
        context?.addLine(to: toPoint)

        context?.setLineCap(.round)
        context?.setLineWidth(CGFloat(eraserBrushWidth))

        context?.setBlendMode(.clear)

        context?.strokePath()

        lassoImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
```

```
lassoImageView // this is UIImageView where I'm loading image from gallery and then erasing image with my finger

lassoOffset // this is Float for touch offset because finger hides part of image
```

Code is simple and it actually works but if image aspect ration is different from UIImageView aspect ratio. UIImageView content mode is set to `Aspect Fit` but anyways when I drag my finger image become stretched like if it was `Scale to Fill`

I believe problem is with my rect in this line:

```
lassoImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: lassoImageView.frame.size.width, height: lassoImageView.frame.size.height))
```

I even tried to calculate image rect itself but in this case image just disappeared after `touches begun`

Maybe my question is noob and I probably missing something ridiculous, but I really really need to figure this out.

Thanks to every one and have a great day

Best, Victor

Answer (score 3):

Oh my...

I just made this

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first as UITouch?{
            let touchPoint = touch.location(in: self.lassoImageView) + lassoOffset!
            print("touch ended at : \(touchPoint)")
            erase(fromPoint: touchPoint, toPoint: touchPoint)
            /*UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(lassoImageView.frame.size)
                lassoImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: lassoImageView.frame.size.width, height: lassoImageView.frame.size.height), blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)
                lassoImageView.image?.draw(in:  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: lassoImageView.frame.size.width, height: lassoImageView.frame.size.height), blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)
                lassoImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()   */
    }
```

and in my `erase` method changed this lines:

```
lassoImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: lassoImageView.frame.size.width, height: lassoImageView.frame.size.height))
```

to this one:

```
lassoImageView.layer.render(in: context!)
```

Not sure what happen here but now it works great

Comment: Hey, have you implemented the "restore" functionality?